# MongoDB: Count values from field whose values is an array

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am very new to MongoDB and I want to use `Aggregation` to solve the following problem. I have a collection like so.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5732fa438acef72abc442ac8"), 
"publisherId" : NumberInt(1), 
"type" : NumberInt(3), 
"qualityInfo" : [
    "FilterOne", 
    "FilterTwo", 
    "FilterThree"
], 
"date" : "2016-05-11 11:24:19"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5732fa438acef72abc442ac9"), 
    "publisherId" : NumberInt(3), 
    "type" : NumberInt(1), 
    "qualityInfo" : [
        "FilterOne", 
        "FilterFour"
    ], 
    "date" : "2016-05-11 11:24:19"
}
```

I want to count the occurrance of each values in `qualityInfo` field and output the result something like the following.

```
{ 
"_id" : "FilterOne", 
"count" : "42"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "FilterTwo", 
    "count" : "30"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "FilterThree", 
    "count" : "12"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "FilterFour", 
    "count" : "43"
}
```

I would prefer to achieve this through `Aggregation` as I have noticed that Aggregation operations are much faster than `MapReduce`. Please correct me if I'm wrong otherwise. So it is possible to do it by Aggregation? In case not, then I have already tried a MapReduce query as follows.

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(
function(){
    for( i = 0; i < this.qualityInfo.length; i++  ){
        emit(this.qualityInfo[i], null);
    }
},
function(names, vals){
    return Array.sum(names);
},
{ query: { publisherId: 2 }, out: "qualityResult" }
```

);

But this doesn't give me a count value. Just returns the name string in both `_id` and `value` in MapReduce result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mongodb aggregation it is an one line simple command.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     { $unwind:"$qualityInfo"}, 
     { $project: {"qualityInfo":1} }, 
     { $group:{
           _id:"$qualityInfo",
           count: {$sum:1}}´
     } 
]);
```

Comment: This query is giving me an empty result. Just nothing.

Comment: Ok I got the problem.  `$project` should come before `$unwind`. And I also have a `$match` in my query which I put in the very beginning. So it works. Thank you!

Comment: glad that it is working. in my opinion $projection should not cause any problem as it is just an option to go to next stage, i guess you have $match of something which is not visible here, and which caused problem..

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there by using map reduce.
Use the following map-reduce functions:

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(
function(){
    for( i = 0; i < this.qualityInfo.length; i++  ){
        emit(this.qualityInfo[i], 1);
    }
},
function(names, vals){
    return Array.sum(vals);
},
{ query: { publisherId: 2 }, out: "qualityResult" }
);
```

By emitting "1" as you value per filtername, you get results like

```
{_id: "filterOne", values[1,1,1]},
{_id: "filterTwo", values[1,1]}
```

By doing the Array.sum with the values, you get the number of occurences of each filter.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. However I have more than 8 million documents and this solution is very slow. I used AMITAVA's Aggregation query which worked better for me. Thanks again anyway. :)